# Problems with PHP Download Timeout on Mobile

Tags: php, download, apache2

Sadly I got a problem with my PHP download script. 
First of all, a file is called via Get Variable. 
Then the script searches for the size, type and gives it to download. 
On my PC, using Chrome, all works like a charm.
But when I'm trying to download a file on my iPhone using Safari, it just loads some pixels of the picture, than stops because the network connection was interrupted :/

```
if(file_exists($file_url) OR @getimagesize($file_url))     {
$size = $row['size'] * 1024; // Dateigröße in Byte umrechnen
header("Content-Type: $type");
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');
header("Content-Length: ". $size);
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
//ob_clean();
ob_end_clean();
flush();
readfile($file_url);
```

Did I do anything wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why you are not started ob first?

Comment: Edit: Will try it immediately. Thank you

Comment: Sadly it did not change anything. The file is also still pending at 90% of the full size. Than after a few seconds, it completes completely (but just on my pc)

Comment: I am wondering even if your image size be wrong. has $row['size'] actuall size?

Comment: the size, saved in the mysql, for this file is 109 (KB). By multiplying it with 1024, I just convert it back to Byte.